# How to build embedding layer with tensorflow for the following model?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tensorboard, sentiment-analysis

This is a keras model for sentiment analysis i need to convert it to tensorflow i couldn’t build embedding layer with tensorflow and using confusion matrix to evaluate this model? And I asked if tf-learn is the-same as tensorflow

```
import os     
import numpy as np  
import pandas as pd  
import tensorflow as tf  
from tensorflow import set_random_seed
set_random_seed(2)
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from sklearn.preprocessing import  LabelEncoder
from keras.utils import to_categorical
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.embeddings import Embedding
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers import Conv1D, MaxPooling1D
from keras.layers import Dense,Activation
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras.callbacks import TensorBoard, ModelCheckpoint
import re
import string
import collections
import time
seed = 10
```

**Read CSV Files**

```
df=pd.read_csv('tweets-pos-neg.csv', usecols = ['text','airline_sentiment'])
df = df.reindex(['text','airline_sentiment'], axis=1) #reorder columns
df=df.apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.lower())
```

**Normalize Text**

```
def normalize(text):
    text= re.sub(r"http\S+", r'', text) 
    text= re.sub(r"@\S+", r'', text)
    punctuation = re.compile(r'[!"#$%&()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~|0-9]')
    text = re.sub(punctuation, ' ', text)
    text= re.sub(r'(.)\1\1+', r'\1', text) 
    return text
```

**Cleaned Text**

```
def prepareDataSets(df):
     sentences=[]
     for index, r in df.iterrows():
         text= normalize(r['text'])
         sentences.append([text,r['airline_sentiment']])
          df_sentences=pd.DataFrame(sentences,columns= 
          ['text','airline_sentiment'])
     return df_sentences
edit_df=prepareDataSets(df)
edit_df=shuffle(edit_df)
X=edit_df.iloc[:,0]
Y=edit_df.iloc[:,1]
```

**Split reviews to tokens**

```
 max_features = 50000
 tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=max_features, split=' ')
 tokenizer.fit_on_texts(X.values)
 #convert review tokens to integers
 X_seq = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(X)
```

**Padding Sequence to make all vectors with the same size according to MAX-length of reviews**

```
seq_len=35
X_pad = pad_sequences(X_seq,maxlen=seq_len)
```

**Convert target value from string to integer**

```
le=LabelEncoder()
Y_le=le.fit_transform(Y)
Y_le_oh=to_categorical(Y_le)
```

**Train-Test-Split**

```
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X_pad,Y_le_oh, test_size 
= 0.33, random_state = 42)
X_train, X_Val, Y_train, Y_Val = train_test_split(X_train,Y_train, test_size 
= 0.1, random_state = 42)
print(X_train.shape,Y_train.shape)
print(X_test.shape,Y_test.shape)
print(X_Val.shape,Y_Val.shape)
```

**Create the model**

```
embedding_vecor_length = 32    #no of vector columns
model_cnn = Sequential()
model_cnn.add(Embedding(max_features, embedding_vecor_length, 
input_length=seq_len))
model_cnn.add(Conv1D(filters=100, kernel_size=2, padding='valid', 
activation='relu', strides=1))
model_cnn.add(MaxPooling1D(2))
model_cnn.add(Flatten())
model_cnn.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model_cnn.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
opt=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001, decay=1e-6)
model_cnn.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=opt, metrics= 
['accuracy'])
print(model_cnn.summary())
```

**Evaluate model**

```
history=model_cnn.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=3, batch_size=32, callbacks=[tensorboard], validation_data=(X_Val, Y_Val))
scores = model_cnn.evaluate(X_test, Y_test, verbose=0)
print("Accuracy: %.2f%%" % (scores[-1]*100))
```

Comment: Apart from converting everything to Tensorflow which is a bit broad and you probably have to do yourself, what have you tried so far and where are you stuck?

Comment: @de1 embedding layer in tensorflow i couldn’t create it i searched more but i couldn’t reach to its shape, and i ask if these steps is correct also in tensorflow

Comment: There are word2vec examples for embeddings: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/representation/word2vec

I think Stackoverflow is not designed for a general code review. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ might be better for that.

Comment: Just to clarify, do you need to convert `model_cnn` from keras to tensorflow (e.g. to use it in production), or do you need to port all this model-building code to tensorflow?  (BTW, `model_cnn.fit()` is part of building the model, not evaluating it; `compile()` is just configuring, not actually doing any model training at the point.)

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to use Tensorflow APIs to train / evaluate, you can build an Estimator using `model_to_estimator` function.

Here's the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/estimators#creating_estimators_from_keras_models) with an example.

Comment: no i need to convert this model to tensorflow instead of keras i know the difference will begin from embedding layer i couldn't build it with tensorflow..